# Type Iterator result to a tuple

Tags: typescript, iterator

Is there a way to specify the type of an Iterator, such that receivers know that the Iterator produces a tuple?

Such that I can do something like this:

```
class Vector2 {
   components: [number, number]

  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield* this.components
  }
}
```

I've tried looking into using a type annotation via. the generic `Generator` interface, however, did not see a way to use it as a tuple.

I've also tried this:

```
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield* this.components as [number, number]
  }
```

but I get this error:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)

when trying to spread:

```
ctx.strokeRect(...new Vector2(1,1), ...new Vector2(1,1))
```

The error appears because when spreading, TypeScript needs to know the length of the array beforehand; it needs to a tuple type, such that it can check that the receiver gets the correct amount of arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can. Typescript can't even handle a `map` over a tuple without widening to an array type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbCMC8MDaBGANAJhwGYBdGAQxVElgHobMFEAjAUwCcc4lWOvn3iAWABQVaDERkADlJYATAHJIU6RhAB0kqQAowaAHxwYAahhYAlDDp8eGYkA

Comment: Stuff like that would just make sense, right? Because map would never be able to change the length of the tuple. If the tuple only has one type, mapping and keeping the tuple type should be allowed.

Comment: This is not currently possible; see [microsoft/TypeScript#42033](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42033) for a relevant feature request.  I can write this up as an answer when I get a chance.